# How to replace hex value in bytes file with python

Tags: python, hex, byte

I have a file inside it with values ​​like this:

55 02 00 00 04 29 00 00 69 00 00 00 14 00 00 00 46 31 35 39 42 37 38 44 41 36 34 35 35 34 36 44 5f 23 23 00 00 00 00 00 14 00 00 00 38 43 36 30 31 31 35 33 43 44 33 35 44 32 42 33 5f 23 23 00 07 00 00 00 33 30 31 30 35 30

I want it to change to this:

55 02 00 00 05 29 00 00 69 00 00 00 14 00 00 00 46 31 35 39 42 37 38 44 41 36 34 35 35 34 36 44 5f 23 23 00 01 00 00 00 14 00 00 00 38 43 36 30 31 31 35 33 43 44 33 35 44 32 42 33 5f 23 23 00 07 00 00 00 33 30 31 30 35 30

I tried like this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
import os
ori = input("Enter the hex value to be replaced: ")
mod = input('Enter the hex value you want to replace:')
oriconvert = bytes(ori,'utf-8')
modconvert = bytes(mod,'utf-8')
with open('hero.bytes','rb') as test:
    test = test.read()
    test = test.replace(oriconvert,modconvert)
with open('hero.bytes', 'wb') as file:
            file.write(test)
```

Comment: I tested it locally and it was properly replaced. Is the problem something else?

Comment: Did it work with hex value in bytes file ?

Comment: I tried the code. It's working okay. One thing to notice is that if you want to replace `04`, you have to put `04`, otherwise it won't work. You have to exactly input the byte you want to replace.

Comment: @Sihan Tawsik Here is my file structure try it and I'm looking forward to the answer :https://drive.google.com/file/d/11XiZejh0OQtzBoOIVuktuMZ7VKBjoj35/view?usp=share_link

Comment: @Brhaka Here is my file structure try it and I'm looking forward to the answer: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11XiZejh0OQtzBoOIVuktuMZ7VKBjoj35/view?usp=share_link